# Week, weekdays and weekend

Tags: word-usage

Is the meaning of 'week' changing? These days a number of texts are using 'week' as an alternative to 'weekdays'.
e.g. *I have a number of meetings lined up in the week, but will be spending my weekend playing golf.*

I see a number of things wrong with the sentence. Am i the only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with the sentence. I hadn't thought about it before, but *week* has different meanings just as *day* has. *During the week* usually = *on weekdays*; *during the day* = *during daytime*, or even *during the working day*.

Comment: And to address the question of whether the meaning is changing: from the OED, this usage existed ca 1000. *"3. The six working days, as opposed to the Sunday; the period from Monday to Saturday inclusive. Cf. weekday n.   Now also meaning five working days, from Monday to Friday inclusive, as opposed to the weekend."*

Comment: @Peter Yes, I've been accustomed to this usage for a fair wodge of that time.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you provide - a business communication - "week" would refer to "work week": Mon through Fri.